# wordpress css tries to load files from child theme instead of parent

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the twenty nineteen theme, when i open posts, Wordpress calls for CSS files in the child theme directory, and i end up with a 404 error...
The correct files are in the parent theme directory and should be called from there.

Code in the functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css', array(), '4.3.1' );
```

Bootstrap loads correctly in the child theme unless i open a post then i get a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider to use

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css', array(), '4.3.1' );
```

And, please, make sure, you have in your child-theme/style.css at the top of the file the sting

```
Template: twentynineteen
```